# Latitude and longitude via a server side script(not js)

Tags: php, google-maps

I am wondering if there is anyway of getting the lat and lang of a place(on Gmaps, Bing, or something else) w/o using javascript since this needs to work through a REST API.

I cannot create a gMaps object (no javscript for the user).

Is there any way of sending an HTTP call to some google/bing api and get the lat and long(or set of possible values) in return?

Comment: are you looking for this [webservices](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/webservices/) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure - you could use the maps api `maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json` and send requests with `curl`

Have a look at the [Web-Serivce](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/webservices/?hl=en) documentation